# Convert json to csv file in JS/C#/MVC4 and populate AccessDB

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, json, csv

I've a problem on my website.
I currently have an application form and submits the form, an email is sent.
I wish I could create a csv file to sending the form. And secondly, to automatically populate my database access via this CSV file.

My ASP form:

```
<div class="submit">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="field"><input id="inputFirstname" type="text" value="First name *" class="watermark" name="firstname"/></div>
        <div class="field"><input id="inputLastname" type="text" value="Last name *" class="watermark" name="lastname"/></div>
        <div class="field"><input id="inputEmail" type="text" value="E-mail *" class="watermark" name="email"/></div>
        <div class="fieldradio" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                <label class="watermark" style="display:inline">Gender *</label>
                    <input id="inputGenderM"  class="watermark"  style="display:inline;width: 10px" name="gender" type="radio"  />
                <label class="watermark"  style="display:inline">M</label>
                    <input id="inputGenderF"  class="watermark"  style="display:inline;width: 10px"  name="gender" type="radio" />
                <label class="watermark"  style="display:inline">F</label>
        </div>
 </div>
 <div class="right">
    <div class="textarea"><textarea id="inputMessage" name="message" class="watermark">Add your message here</textarea></div>                               
    <div style="float:left;width:100%; margin-top:30px;">
    <div id="captchadiv"><input id="captchaInput" type="text" value="Enter validation text *" name="captchaInput" class="watermark" style="margin-top:10px;"/></div>
   </div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
   <div class="submit_container" id="submitArea">
       <a onclick="javascript:submitCV();" class="btn orange height_19 submit"><span>
        SEND FORM</span></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

My function JS "submitCV()" :

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){

        $.getJSON('http://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=?',
    function(data){
      clientIP = data.ip;
    });

 function submitCV() {
    if( $("#inputFirstname").val() == false)
    {
        $('#inputFirstname').addClass('errorValidationSubmit');
        alert('Please fill the FirstName field ');
        return;
    }
    if($("#inputLastname").val() == false)
    {
        $('#inputLastname').addClass('errorValidationSubmit');
        alert('Please fill the LastName field ');
        return;
    }

    var genderId = $('input[name=gender]:checked').attr('id');
    if(typeof genderId == 'undefined')
    {
        $('.fieldradio').addClass('errorValidationSubmit');

        alert('Please choose a gender ');
        return;
    }

    if( validateEmail($("#inputEmail").val()) == false)
    {
        $('#inputEmail').addClass('errorValidationSubmit');
        alert('Invalid e-mail address.');           
        return;
    }       
    if( $(".submit .dropdown dt a").attr('href') =="#"){
        $('.submit .dropdown').addClass('errorValidationSubmit');
        alert('Please select an open position');
        return;
    }           

    if($("#captchaInput").val() == false || $("#captchaInput").val().length != 5)
    {
        $('#captchaInput').addClass('errorValidationSubmit');
        $('.realperson-text').addClass('errorValidationSubmit');
        alert('Please fill the Validation Text Field with the Captcha (5 characters)');
        return;
    }


    var path = $(location).attr('href');

    var capchallenge = cleanJSONString($(".realperson-hash").val());
        //Recaptcha.get_challenge();
    var capresponse = cleanJSONString($("#captchaInput").val());
        //Recaptcha.get_response();
    try {
        var parameters = '{  "url" : "' + escape(path) + 
                        '", "clientip" : "' + clientIP +
                        '", "firstname" : "' + cleanJSONString($("#inputFirstname").val()) + 
                        '", "lastname" : "' + cleanJSONString($("#inputLastname").val()) + 
                        '", "gender" : "' + cleanJSONString(genderId) + 
                        '", "email" : "' + cleanJSONString($("#inputEmail").val()) + 
                        '", "message" : "' + cleanJSONString($("#inputMessage").val()) + 
                        '", "position" : "' + cleanJSONString($(".submit_cv .dropdown dt a").attr('href')) +                            
                         '", "captchachallenge" : "' + capchallenge + 
                        '", "captcharesponse" : "' + capresponse  + '" }';

        contentSubmit = $("#submitArea").html();
        $("#submitArea").empty().html('<img src="/Style%20Library/ajax-loader.gif" />');

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '_vti_bin/json/monservice.svc/submit',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: parameters,
            success: function (msg) {
                submitSucceeded(msg);
                $("#submitArea").empty().html(contentSubmit);
                 resetRealPersonCaptcha();
                 alert(parameters);
            },
            error: submitFailed
        });
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert('Error invoking service' + e);
        clearUploadPart();
    }
    //Recaptcha.reload();
}   
function submitSucceeded(result) {
    alert(result.submitResult);

    if (!result.submitResult.contains("The captcha verification didn't work. Please try again")) {
        clearUploadPart();
    } 
}
function submitFailed(error) {
    alert('An error occured.');
    //clearUploadPart();
    resetRealPersonCaptcha();
    $("#submitArea").empty().html(contentSubmit);
}
```

Is there a relatively quick opportunity to put in place to create a CSV file to be stored in one place?
What do you recommend?

On the other hand, I want that every new CSV file, I can populate an Access database.
If my CSV files on a FTP folder, you it is the possibility of a Unix script or simply VB?

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to get the JSON data from the form, Use the following method JSONTOCSVConverter :

```
function JSONToCSVConvertor(JSONData, ReportName, ShowLabel) {

       //If JSONData is not an object then JSON.parse will parse the JSON string in an Object
       var arrData = typeof JSONData != 'object' ? JSON.parse(JSONData) : JSONData;

       var CSV = '';
       if (ShowLabel) {
           var row = "";
           //This loop will extract the label from 1st index of on array
          for (var index in arrData[0]) {
              //Now convert each value to string and comma-seprated
               row += index + ',';
          }
           row = row.slice(0, -1);

           //append Label row with line break
           CSV += row + '\r\n';
       }
       //1st loop is to extract each row
       for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
           var row = "";
           //2nd loop will extract each column and convert it in string comma-seprated
           for (var index in arrData[i]) {
               row += '"' + arrData[i][index] + '",';
           }
           row.slice(0, row.length - 1);
           //add a line break after each row
           CSV += row + '\r\n';
       }
       if (CSV == '') {
           alert('No data available');
           return;
       }
       //this will remove the blank-spaces from the title and replace it with an underscore
       var fileName = ReportName.replace(/ /g, "_");

       //Initialize file format you want csv or xls
       var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);

       //this trick will generate a temp <a /> tag
       var link = document.createElement("a");
       link.href = uri;

       //set the visibility hidden so it will not effect on your web-layout
       link.style = "visibility:hidden";
       link.download = fileName + ".csv";

       //this part will append the anchor tag and remove it after automatic click
       document.body.appendChild(link);
       link.click();
       document.body.removeChild(link);
   }
```

Comment: Thank you!
I do not see how to use this feature?
I use the "Submit" function of a button, when should I call the JSONTOCSVConverter function?
Should I apply it on my data "Parameters"?
Or do I give the path to the CSV file?

Comment: Do you have a extra button to create the csv file or do you want to create it at the moment you submit the form?

Comment: Yes, i want to create it at the moment you submit the form and it's my difficulty

Comment: My script allows me to get my json, but I can't automatically create my file(csv) when the user submits the form ...

Comment: In the sample fiddle above you are able to get the csv file when user submits the form.
You need to call the JSONToCSVConverter method inside the submit method call.

Comment: It's possible to save the csv file directly without the pop-up asking to save the file?

Comment: For me the csv file gets saved directly. Are you getting any pop-up asking to save the file??

Comment: You can call another method inside the submit call.
$('form').submit(function() {
            
   $('#result').text(JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()));
            var jsonData =     JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject());
            JSONToCSVConvertor(jsonData, "Report", true);
            return false;
        });
http://jsfiddle.net/sxGtM/5712/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but in my form i use already :

```
<div class="submit_container" id="submitArea">
    <a onclick="javascript:submit();" class="btn orange height_19 submit"><span>
        SEND FORM</span></a>
</div>
```

It's possible to call another method inside the submit method call ?

Or i must add at this function ?

```
    $(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $('#result').text(JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()));
        return false;
    });
});
```